# Tools to detect memory(array of structures) getting over-written

Tags: c, debugging, memory

Could anyone guide me to a suitable tool to debug a C program? Its not a simple one and part of a big project. The problem is that I have an array of structures and it is initialised properly. I could check the values using gdb. After the program runs, somewhere the array contents are being over-written. I am not sure which process is over-writing the contents of this array of structures. Any tool or even a technique within gdb to track this problem? Can't do watchpoint from gdb because it can't watch a "constant value". Tried valgrind, but doesn't show any memory related issues. Any help, really appreciated. thanks, badri.

Comment: Have a look at IBM/Rational's [PurifyPlus](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0306_chitale/) I've used this long time ago and it was amazing.

Comment: In case the code writes to a `const` declared variable or assignes one to a non `const` by intention you should get a compiler warning, at least with all warnings on: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Is the memory for array of structures on the stack, i.e. auto variables, or, on the heap, i.e. memory obtained via malloc? Also, what environment are you working with, Windows or Linux/BSD?

Comment: its on the stack. working on linux.

Comment: thanks alk. its showing me a few extra warnings now for me to debug.

Comment: requested a license for purify-plus too. thnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GDB it is always possible to watch some address. If you can get the address of something in `gdb`:

```
   p &somecomplexthing
```

and it is answering you `0x123456` you can always

```
  watch *(void**)0x123456
```

(or use whatever pointer-to-pointer type is appropriate for you)

Beware of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR); you may want to disable it

(perhaps with `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to be run as root).

Also, recent [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) gives you the [address sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) with `-fsanitize=address`; and don't forget the `-Wall -g` flags to GCC.